# TableView Json Swift

Tags: json, swift, tableview

I currently developing an app which list user object by making an request to a webservice, which send a response in JSON in this format :

```
{
 "0":
 {
  "id":"30",
  "title":"galaxys6",
  "price":"550",
  "description":"neuf",
  "addedDate":"2015-07-16 15:04:24",
  "user_id":"2",
  "user_name":"",
  "user_zipCode":"69003",
  "category_id":"1",
  "category_label":"PHONE",
  "subcategory_id":"1",
  "subcategory_label":"Phone",
  "picture":"",
  "bdd":{},
  "picture_url":"http:\/\/jdl-barreme-orange.dyndns.org\/WEBSERVICE\/pictures\/galaxy s6.JPG"
 },
 "1":
 {
  "id":"31",
  "title":"iphone4",
  "price":"570",
  "description":"neuf",
  "addedDate":"2015-07-16 15:14:54",
  "user_id":"2",
  "user_name":"",
  "user_zipCode":"69003",
  "category_id":"1",
  "category_label":"PHONE",
  "subcategory_id":"1",
  "subcategory_label":"Phone",
  "picture":"",
  "bdd":{},
  "picture_url":"http:\/\/jdl-barreme-orange.dyndns.org\/WEBSERVICE\/pictures\/iphone.JPG"
 },
}
```

For each object my webservice create a dictionary (0;1;2;3....)

I search a method to retrieve for each dictionary the value title and price and put them in a tableView.

Code I used (tableviewcontroller) :

```
if let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as? NSDictionary{

            // 4
             if let resp = jsonData["1"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                NSLog("%@", resp)
                // 5
                for item in resp {
                    repositories.append(Repository(jsonData: item))
                }
```

repository controller :

```
class Repository {

var name: String?
var description: String?
var html_url: String?

init(jsonData: NSDictionary) {
    self.name = jsonData["id"] as? String
    self.description = jsonData["description"] as? String
    self.html_url = jsonData["title"] as? String
}
}
```

But it doesn't work, I put a breakpoint, and xcode stop to interpret here :

```
if let resp = jsonData["1"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                NSLog("%@", resp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get the title and price for your JSON:

```
if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    for (_, value) in json {
        if let dict = value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
                println(title)
            }
            if let price = dict["price"] as? String {
                println(price)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be used to init your Repository classes if you want:

```
class Repository {

    var name: String?
    var description: String?
    var html_url: String?

    init(jsonData: [String:AnyObject]) {
        self.name = jsonData["id"] as? String
        self.description = jsonData["description"] as? String
        self.html_url = jsonData["title"] as? String
    }
}

var repos = [Repository]()

if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    for (_, value) in json {
        if let dict = value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            let repo = Repository(jsonData: dict)
            repos.append(repo)
        }
    }
}

for repo in repos {
    println(repo.name)
    println(repo.description)
    println(repo.html_url)
}
```

In the loop I'm ignoring the key: `for (_, value) in json` but you can use it if needed of course:

```
for (key, value) in json {
    println(key)  // "1", "2", ...
    // ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Following your comment asking how to use this answer if your data format is different: if you want an array of dictionaries, change the typecast of the `NSJSONSerialization` result to reflect that: `[[String:AnyObject]]`. Next you can iterate over your array to get each dictionary properties:

```
if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
    for dict in jsonArray {
        if let title = dict["title"] as? String {
            println(title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: last question, it is possible to use this code if i have something like that in my JSON : {"objects":[{"id":"28","title":"test","price":"56 ... instead of {
 "0":
 {
  "id":"30",
  "title":"galaxys6",
  "price":"550"... ?

Comment: thank's for the explanations, it's easier to understand with however it does not work, if i put a breakpoint on : "if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: nil, error: nil) as? [[String:AnyObject]]" , xcode doesn't execute the next code " for dict in jsonArray" thank you again for the time you wast with me !

Comment: Test your actual JSON with http://jsonlint.com/ for validity. I've checked my update with the example you gave in the comment and it works ok. If there's still a problem then maybe it's time to create a whole new question with details about this specific new error. :)

Comment: yeah your're right, for information, my JSON is valid, i just think i have to modify my code to enter in the Objects field and next to retrieve the value for each of my objects. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You are making a mistake here

```
if let resp = jsonData["1"] as? [NSDictionary]
```

This should be a `NSDictionary` not `[NSDictionary]`, (which would be an array of dictionaries).

Also this conditional block

```
if let reposArray = jsonData["items"] as? [NSDictionary]
```

will never be executed because `jsonData` does not contain a key "items".

Comment: I already tried with NSDictionary instead of [NSDictionary], but i got : "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Repository' with an argument list of type '(jsonData: (key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject))'". Of course you're right, it 's a mistake, "if let reposArray = jsonData["items"] as? [NSDictionary] " provide from an other controller , sorry.

Comment: Good, we are closing in on the problem. Start by up-voting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the [NSDictionary]

```
if let resp = jsonData["1"] as? [NSDictionary]
```

[NSDictionary] is array of NSDictionary same as `Array<NSDictionary>`
just remove the brackets [] and change to

```
if let resp = jsonData["1"] as? NSDictionary
```

Comment: I already tried with NSDictionary instead of [NSDictionary], but i got : "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Repository' with an argument list of type '(jsonData: (key: AnyObject, value: AnyObject))'".